# Is A duplicate of B or is it the other way round?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

While working with the Reopen queue I hit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605535/what-are-documentation-comments-in-xcode).
It was closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168423/what-are-the-new-documentation-commands-available-in-xcode-5).

So I was just about to click on *Leave Closed* but **wait!!!** OP's comment is right.
The message says: *This question has been asked before and already has an answer.*
OP's comment says: *"This question has been asked before." So 2011 > 2013? :-p*

Shall we somehow invert the situation?

Why is this user being accused that his question asked in **2011** is a duplicate of question asked in **2013**?
One may think that this particular user doesn't pay attention and made no effort to search for similar question on SO. This is unfair.

Comment: Normally duplicates are from past posts, but they don't have to. It's better to keep the one that has more information, even if it's "in the future". I, however, cannot make that judgement call.

Comment: Backticks are *for code*, not for emphasis.

Comment: @gnat I didn't think about it from the perspective of _better or not_. Since __duplicate__ is one of the reasons to close the question, I always considered this as so called _serious issue_ in the question. Basically __Vote to close = OP did something wrong__ to me. Now I think I was wrong. Anyway it's funny to have a duplicate question about duplicates :)

Comment: vote to close as a dupe is different, it doesn't typically mean OP did anything wrong, see [Dr. Strangedupe...](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Comment: Oh, the irony of this being a duplicate question :P

Comment: @DrewMcGowen I've noticed that most questions about duplicates are themselves duplicates. It's happened to me twice.

Comment: As a strong indicator of how "not wrong" it is to ask duplicate questions, SE sites don't give you negative points for it being marked duplicate. Indeed, IMHO, asking duplicate question is good because it helps searches reach the right answer (all duplicate questions should point to the best answer). I have frequently asked people to close my own questions as duplicate to help the system link the questions together. In my opinion it generally doesn't matter which question is closed as long as the closing is done in order to link the questions.

Comment: As for why I don't close my own questions as duplicates I prefer to let other people choose in order to avoid my own voting bias.

Comment: @slebetman well in my own questions, I prefer to vote dupe myself [as soon as I am pointed to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773) "Since I found an answer, I just don't need my question anymore, and the sooner I get it closed, the less I will need to worry about it in the future..."

Comment: @gnat: In my case my questions tend to get answered before duped. Or in one case been told that my question is phrased better. So I let "the people" chose which deserves to be canonical.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A duplicate is not meant to be which question was asked *first*.  It's meant to be which question is *better*.  I agree that the message is a little misleading, but that's how it's meant to work.

Often, there will be a canonical question made, and questions, new or old, will be made duplicates of that question because the question is usually more descriptive and the answers are both more helpful and more in depth.  Duplicates are meant to help future users.  By pointing them to a better question, odds are higher that they will have their question answered.

Comment: I propose to change the sentence from "This question has been asked before and" to something else, just to avoid this kind of misunderstanding. Although it also seems the "non-duplicate" question-answer pair follows my setup of answering the question myself with the goal of writing a reference question. :-p

Comment: Yes, it is a bit confusing. You could make a feature request here for such a change if you want.